# Tiff File Compression in java

Tags: java

How to compress the tiff file in java, when i am adding the jpeg files to tiff ,the file size was increasing

File f2 = new File("D:/KYCDATA/mani/myimage_compressed.jpeg");

```
    BufferedImage image3 = ImageIO.read(f2);
    List<BufferedImage> list = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();
    list.add(image3);

    File tiffFile = new File("D:/KYCDATA/mani/mani.tiff");
    if(tiffFile.exists()) {
        tiffFile.delete();
    }
    ImageOutputStream ios = null;
    ImageWriter writer = null;
    Iterator it = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("tiff");
    if (it.hasNext()) {
        writer = (ImageWriter) it.next();
    }

    ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(tiffFile);
    writer.setOutput(ios);

    IIOImage iioImage = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        iioImage = new IIOImage(list.get(i), null, null);
        if (i == 0) {
            writer.write(iioImage);
        } else {
            writer.writeInsert(i, iioImage, null);
        }
        writer.endWriteSequence();
```

Answer (score 3):

TIFF uses lossless compression so if I'm understanding your question correctly I'd expect the TIFF to be larger than the original JPEG. See here for a simple description:

http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/imagetypes.htm

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set compression mode on the ImageWriteParam object and then pass this param to the writer.

**Add the below code to get the default writer params and set the compression mode**

```
ImageWriteParam writeParam = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
param.setCompressionType("PackBits");
```

**modify your code to add writeParam that we set above to write method**

```
   if (i == 0) {
        writer.write( null,iioImage,writeParam);
    } else {
        writer.writeInsert(i, iioImage, writeParam);
    }
```